# Cookie Does Not Contain The secure and HTTPOnly Attribute

Tags: nginx, security, node.js, cookies

While running a Qualys Vulnerability Scan on a website which is being developed I got the following vulnerability:

`Cookie Does Not Contain The "HTTPOnly" Attribute`

`Cookie Does Not Contain The "secure" Attribute`

My application running in `ExpressJS`, `NodeJS` and `nginx` web server. I am using express-session and csurf token. I have already set both `HTTPOnly` and `secure` flag true. Configuration is the following:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false, limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../public")));

app.enable("trust proxy");
app.use(expressSession({
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: `session_db`
    }),
    secret: `session_secret`,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    proxy: true,
    rolling: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: false,
        maxAge: (72 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    },
    unset: "destroy"
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());

app.use("/api", api);

app.use( csrf({
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true
    }
}));//csrf
```

And my nginx configuration is:

```
 location / {
                proxy_pass http://nodejs;
                proxy_set_header Host $host ;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure";
        }
```

`HTTPOnly` and `secure` both flags are ticked in browser cookies section. but when I scan it, It shows me above mentioned vulnerabilities.

can someone help me?

Await your help friends